# How to find the duplicates in NSMutableDictionary?

Tags: ios, nsarray, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

pseudo code:

```
NSArray *arr1 = {"mike","george","Tim","Tom"...}
NSArray *arr2 = {"mike","george","Chris","Adam"...}
NSArray *arr3 = {"Don","george","mike","Tom"...}
NSArray *arr4 = {"george","Nicole","Moe","mike"...}

//Add these arrays to the dictionary
for(int i=0; i<n, i++)
   [dictionary addObject:arr[i]];
```

I would like to find the duplicate value(s) that exists in ALL of the arrays, not some. 
In this example, the value would be {"george","mike"}.

Comment: Do you mean elements that are common to all of the arrays? Also, how does this work, NSDictionary doesn't have the method 'addObject:'. Is your dictionary object an NSArray as well?

Comment: Sorry its NSMutableDictionary - Yes, common to all arrays.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming `dictionary` is actually an NSMutableArray, then something like this will work:

```
NSMutableArray *results = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(NSString *name in [dictionary objectAtIndex:0]) {
    bool valid = true;
    for(int i=1;i<[dictionary count];i++) {
        if([[dictionary objectAtIndex:i] indexOfObject:name]==NSNotFound) {
            valid=false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(valid)
        [results addObject:name];
}
```

Comment: Great - My code uses NSMutableDictionary, but I was able to make the changes.

Comment: [NSMutableDictionaryInstance values] or [NSMutableDictionaryInstance keys] will yield an NSArray for you to walk through with the for loop above.

Comment: @SMA2012, you should get your terms straight -- you do not have a mutable dictionary, or this code wouldn't work. What you have is a mutable array.

Comment: @rdelmar- the above is a psuedo code. I have a mutableDictionary and it works fine. thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
NSArray *arr1 = @[@"mike",@"george",@"Tim",@"Tom" ];
NSArray *arr2 = @[@"mike",@"george",@"Chris",@"Adam" ];
NSArray *arr3 = @[@"Don",@"george",@"mike",@"Tom" ];
NSArray *arr4 = @[@"george",@"Nicole",@"Moe",@"mike" ];

NSMutableSet *intersection = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:arr1];
[intersection intersectSet:[NSSet setWithArray:arr2]];
[intersection intersectSet:[NSSet setWithArray:arr3]];
[intersection intersectSet:[NSSet setWithArray:arr4]];

NSArray *duplicates = [intersection allObjects];

NSLog(@"duplicates=%@", duplicates);
```

duplicates contains an array with the values which appear in them all:

```
duplicates=(
  mike,
  george
)
```

Comment: Thanks- this is another easy method besides the one I accepted as an answer. I tried this method and works great too.